# Can I do a git mv with egit?

Tags: eclipse, git

I can do on the command line:

```
$ git mv foo bar
```

and after this I commit.

Can I do  `git mv` also in eclipse with `egit`?

Comment: `git mv` is basicly `mv <oldfile> <newfile>; git rm <oldfile>; git add <newfile>`, git does not track renames as renames, just as deletions and insertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if in ***Window > Preferences: Team > Git > Committing*** the option ***Automatically stage files being moved*** is enabled, both the deleted old file and the new file are added to the index (alias staging area). This is the same behavior as with [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv).

Note, in Git there is no real/atomic `mv`: a commit of a moved file consists of a deletion of a file plus an addition of a file. Instead, Git tries to detect moving/renaming. Currently in Eclipse in the *History* view, moved files are shown correctly with their history, but e. g. *cherry pick* will fail because of the missing rename detection in JGit (see [Eclipse bug 372606](http://eclip.se/372606)).